# Creation of a big table with edit button for each record

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I have a very big html table generated like this:

```
function getSpeciesRowHtml(row_data) {
    var html = "";
    html = html + '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.id + '<input type="hidden" class="species_table_IDs" value="' + row_data.id + '"></td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.name + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.name_lat + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.class + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.family + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.family_lat + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.order + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.order_lat + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + row_data.spec_status + '</td>' +
    '<td><a class="btn_species_delete">Edit</a></td>' + //delete button
    '</tr>'
    ;
    return html;
}


function fillTable(data) {
    var html = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        html = html + getSpeciesRowHtml(data[i],true);
    });
    $('#species_table tbody')
            .prepend($(html));
};
```

Data for this table comes from database through controller.
The fact is that the data can be deleted. For this purpose in each row of the table there is the button "Delete".
Delete buttons are initialized by class selector because them very much (a line by line table creation takes a monstrous amount of time):

```
$('.btn_species_delete')
        .button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash" }, text: false })
        .click(function () { DeleteSpecies(id); });
```

That is, when you press the "delete" function must be called which should be referred to the "id" property. The problem is that each button has its own unique "id" and I have not idea how to transfer it there. Because initialization of buttons is performed through the whole class.
How best to handle this, for this to work as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data attribute to you `<a>`, for example

```
'<a class="btn_species_delete" data-rowid="'+row_data.id+'">'
```

then in your onclick:

```
DeleteSpecies($(this).attr('data-rowid'));
```

Comment: oh. it was so easy. Thank you a lot

Comment: @DimaRailguner you should probably mark this as the answer if you used this :D so others may learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't it be easier to do this:

```
$('#species_table .btn_species_delete')
    .button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash" }, text: false })
    .click(function () { 
        DeleteSpecies($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
```

`$(this)` is referring the button that was clicked and `.attr('id')` gets it ID value

hope this helps.

check out the following links for more info:

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/ - explains `$(this)`

http://api.jquery.com/attr/ - explains `.attr()`

**edit**

all this assumes that the button's id is the same as the row id :D see Michaels answer and combine the 2